# Bash Script to launch multiple processes in parallel and in different terminal sessions or all in one foreground?

Tags: bash, shell-script

**Problem Background**

In my development environment I need to have a couple of development web servers running on different ports. Mostly REST API services. Every time I start coding I have to open up a bunch of terminals and start the services in each one and remember what port each one is etc it's a mission.

**Existing Solutions**

This answer provides a way to write a script that would run the commands to launch all the servers and keep them running in parallel.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script

**Limitation of Solution**

I do need to see the logs for each of these services though so I can't just have one in the foreground.

**Question**

Is there a way to either (a) Open multiple terminal sessions from the bash script or (b) Even having them all log to the same session could work (I can make the log messages identify the source).

**Further**

If there's perhaps a solution that uses tmux I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) (ruby) which allows to pre-define tmux sessions in YAML configuration-files.

Alternatives are [tmuxp](https://tmuxp.readthedocs.io) (python) and [teamocil](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil) (ruby).

Comment: Yea this can definitely work. Thank!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm using **tmuxinator** to start project-containers, tail logs, ... etc. for years now. Works well. The template function is quite nice too if you happen to have multiple similar projects.